# installing visual studio 2005 after 2008 already installed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2005

I have a machine with VS 2008/Sql 2008 already installed.  I now need to install an instance of vs 2005/Sql 2005 for two reasons.

The main reason is for reporting Services 2005.  All of the report servers are sql 2005.
Now to create a SSRS compatible with 2005 do I just need to install Sql Server 2005 and work with it in VS 2008 or do I also need to install VS 2005.

The second reason is the off-site team that I am consulting with do not want the project upgraded yet.

So without rebuilding the whole box is there a safe way to install VS 2005 on a box that already contains 2008?

Same question for Sql Server 2005?

Thanks

Comment: VS 2005 went in fine.  Sql 2005, create an instance of the server fine but it will not install the Client Compontents including the 

Management Tools and BI Developement stuff saying 
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Setup
------------------------------
None of the selected features can be installed or upgraded. Setup cannot proceed since no effective change is being made to the machine. To continue, click Back and then select features to install. To exit SQL Server Setup, click Cancel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing VS 2005 first and then installing Sql 2005 with the command switch SKUUPGRADE=1 seems to have done it.

Answer (score 3):

I have 2005 (VS/SQL), 2008 (VS/SQL) and 2010 (VS only) installed side by side and it works fine.  However, it can become confusing exactly which version of SQL is which (if anyone has a good tip for that let me know).  I didn't have any particular issues, just installed out of the box and it worked.

Having said that, the Virtual PC route that AaronLS recommends is worth considering.

Comment: I name my databases instances SQL2000, SQL2005, SQL2008 and the shortcuts similarly.

Comment: @Joshua: Makes sense :-)  I just ran the default installers without too much thought behind it and accepted default naming for the instances.

Comment: All excellent suggestions.  I personally work off a laptop and don't like all those services to be running and taking up resources.  You can set the services to a manual setup type so they don't start on bootup, and have a batch script you run as-needed to start the service when needed for development testing: `net start MSSQL$SQL2005`

Comment: @AaronLS: Good point.  I use net start/net stop batch files too.  By default all services I don't need every day are off.  Even though I'm on a desktop, it's still a 32-bit OS with 4GB and with lots of stuff installed, that bogs down too.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would use VirtualPC and install the SQL server in a virtual machine.  You can use the Microsoft Loopback Connector to connect your local host machine to the guest machine.

Answer (score 1):

VS and SQL Server 2008/2005 work fine side by side, and I believe you don't need anything special to make it work. You'll have to use an instance name that isn't taken for SQL Server, but that's about it.